# Count number of occurence for unique data in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

So I know that if I was looking to count the number of entry that has the same city name, I will use the code below:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM location
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY count
DESC
```

How would I go about doing it if I want to count the number of entries with the same city name and state name?

citynameA, stateNameB = number of entries with both the same cityname and statename

Comment: `GROUP BY city, state` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple fields with group by, e.g.

```
SELECT city, state, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM location
GROUP BY city, state
ORDER BY count
DESC
```

Comment: Might want to order by `count, state, city`.